# jQuery custom draggable control slide without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have successfully made a custom control-slider, but it's not draggable. I tried searching for solutions online but most of them use jQuery UI.

http://jsfiddle.net/LWabn/1/

How do I make the control-slide-button draggable and dynamically update the value of the `input` field?

Comment: why don't you want to use jquery UI? if you need the exact functionality, i recommend looking at jquery UI's source code...

Comment: Because I only want the dragging functionality.

Comment: Also, if you are using Angular 4, jQuery-UI seems basically impossible get to work with it, giving a typings related error even after jqueryui typings are installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the basic template for draggable slider without jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/TGd96/

Comment: Magical, Thank you so much. I'll try to understand the code and I'm really thankful.

Comment: Holy smokes - talk about a great answer.