# How to create a range slider without plugins and Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, rangeslider

I try to study javascript and stuck. I want to understand how make a range slider by myself. But everyone uses plugins and libs like jquery UI. or tries stylize input type="range", although this does not supported in IE9. It's good and simple but i want improve my skills. I can't find tutorial about this subject. 
May be somebody knows something about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery custom draggable control slide without jQuery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767844/jquery-custom-draggable-control-slide-without-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some trivial hints:

- have a div, which is the body of the slider
- have a floating div on top of that, which you can drag with your mouse
- implement dragging code on the floating div (ensure it remains in the slider area)
- in this same code you can do some sort of calculations, and calculate a "value" for the slider, e.g. in percent.

Of course you can pick a ready-made slider lib such as http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/range_slider.html and learn more about the implementation.

This is also quite light: http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/

Another workaround is actually creating something which is *not* a slider. But something similar. At the bottom of this> [Is there a simple JavaScript slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173046/is-there-a-simple-javascript-slider) you can see a screenshot of a segmented volume control. That is in fact just a set of images with mouse events on top of it. Nothing fancy, not nice, but on the other hand works with any browser since JS has been invented :)

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I've found amazing solution In your last link. 
Here this sweetie http://jsfiddle.net/LucP/BPdKR/2/

Answer (score 0):

A very minimal slider.  For IE and Microsoft Edge.

html:

```
<input type="range" />
```

javascript:

```
::-ms-thumb {
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
}
::-ms-track {
    height: 2px;
    color: transparent;
}
```

[image]